# Android ExpandableListView with different children types

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have an expandable List View in my application. When all the children are TextView all works fine.
But now I am trying to have differents children types. That's mean that for example for the first group I want to have TextView children, for the second group I want to have EditText children and for all the others groups I want to have radioButton children.
I tried to code it but I get a BUG . For the same group I get different types of Views(EditTexts,RadioButtons and TextViews). I think it is due to the **convetView** because on the first click all in OK and then the problems begin.

This is my getChildView method:

```
public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
    boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   final String laptop = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
   LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();

if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_item, null);
}
TextView item=null;
EditText itemEdit=null;
RadioButton itemRadio=null;

item = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.laptop);
itemEdit = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.laptopEdit);
itemRadio = (RadioButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.laptopRadio);

if(groupPosition==0){
     itemEdit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
     itemRadio.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}else if(groupPosition==1){
    item.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    itemRadio.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}else{
    itemEdit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    item.setVisibility(View.GONE);

}

ImageView delete = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.delete);
delete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builder.setMessage("Do you want to remove?");
        builder.setCancelable(false);
        builder.setPositiveButton("Yes",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
  List<String> child =laptopCollections.get(laptops.get(groupPosition));
                        child.remove(childPosition);
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                });
        builder.setNegativeButton("No",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
        AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
    }
});

if(groupPosition==0)
        item.setText(laptop);
    else if(groupPosition==1)
        itemEdit.setText(laptop);
    else
        itemRadio.setText(laptop);

return convertView;
}
```

This is my "child_item.xml"

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:padding="10dp"
   android:background="#196387">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/laptop"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:paddingLeft="25dp" 
    android:textColor="#dddddd"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/laptopEdit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:paddingLeft="25dp" 
    android:textColor="#dddddd"/>

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/laptopRadio"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:paddingLeft="25dp" 
    android:textColor="#dddddd"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/delete"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_delete"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```